# How to fit a model I built to another data set and get residuals?

Tags: r, statistics

I fitted a mixed model to Data A as follows:

```
model <- lme(Y~1+X1+X2+X3, random=~1|Class, method="ML", data=A)
```

Next, I want to see how the model fits Data B and also get the estimated residuals. Is there a function in R that I can use to do so?

(I tried the following method but got all new coefficients.)

```
model <- lme(Y~1+X1+X2+X3, random=~1|Class, method="ML", data=B)
```

Comment: Did you try `predict(model,data_B) - data_B$Y` or something like that?

Comment: Not yet since I did not know about that. Thanks!

Comment: You should use prediction with caution. Small changes to the model can lead to different outcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason you are getting new coefficients in your second attempt with `data=B` is that the function `lme` returns a model fitted to your data set using the formula you provide, and stores that model in the variable `model` as you have selected.

To get more information about a model you can type `summary(model_name)`. the `nlme` library includes a method called `predict.lme` which allows you to make predictions based on a fitted model.  You can type `predict(my_model)` to get the predictions using the original data set, or type `predict(my_model, some_other_data)` as mentioned above to generate predictions using that model but with a different data set.

In your case to get the residuals you just need to subtract the predicted values from observed values.  So use `predict(my_model,some_other_data) - some_other_data$dependent_var`, or in your case `predict(model,B) - B$Y`.

Answer (score 2):

*You model:*

> model <- lme(Y~1+X1+X2+X3, random=~1|Class, method="ML", data=A)

*2 predictions based on your model:*

> pred1=predict(model,newdata=A,type='response')
>
> pred2=predict(model,newdata=B,type='response')

*missed: A function that calculates the percent of false positives, with cut-off set to 0.5. 

(predicted true but in reality those observations were not positive)*

> missed = function(values,prediction){sum(((prediction > 0.5)*1) !=
> values)/length(values)}
>
> missed(A,pred1) 
> missed(B,pred2)